# java Label automatic fontsize

Tags: java, label, font-size

I have an SWT Label which shows different single line texts loaded from files. Is there a way to automatically adjust the fontsize so that when long text comes the fontsize goes smaller and the Label still shows the full text?
When Label has no such property, is it possible to calculate the size of the String using a font and fontsize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my understanding. your Label width is fixed (assume 200). the string that you read needs 300 pixels to fit with the current font. You can calculate the size required to draw by using `GC.textExtent(String)`

Try this working example

```
  private static boolean setText(Label label, String txt, Font font)
  {

    int height = font.getFontData()[0].getHeight();
    GC gc = new GC(label);
    gc.setFont(font);
    Point size = gc.textExtent(txt);
    Rectangle bounds = label.getBounds();
    int diff = bounds.width-size.x;
    if(diff >= 0 || height <=2)
    {
      label.setFont(font);
      label.setText(txt);
      return true;
    }
    else
    {

      String name = font.getFontData()[0].getName();
      int style = font.getFontData()[0].getStyle();
      FontData data = new FontData(name, Math.max(1,height-1), style);
      Font newFont = new Font(Display.getCurrent(), data);
      if(!setText(label, txt, newFont))
      {
        newFont.dispose();
      }
    }
    gc.dispose();
    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {



    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setSize(600, 300);

    Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    label.setBounds(20, 20, 100, 50);
    setText(label, "hello stackoverflow!!!!!!", Display.getDefault().getSystemFont());
    shell.open();


    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();


  }
```